# How to write complete dictionary in existing csv file in loop using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I want to write the dictionary into an existing `.CSV` in the new column within the loop.

My sample code :

```
for loop:
   keys = []
   values = []
   dictionary = {}`
for loop:
   dictionary = dict(zip(keys,values)
```

Write code for inserting dictionary in csv file in first loop.

My dictionary data is

```
{ 'string': value, 'string': value }
```

My desired CSV data should be :

```
Count
{'string':value, 'string':value}
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output along with what you have tried. It is quite unclear what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like that?

```
dict_test = { 'string1': 22, 'string2': 33 }

with open("test.csv", "w+") as file:
    file.write(str(dict_test))
```

As output in the file you would get:

> {'string1': 22, 'string2': 33}